# Why doesn't dereferencing a nil pointer in unsafe.Sizeof() cause a panic?

Tags: go, pointers, runtime-error

https://go.dev/play/p/X_BH4qGgXHJ

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var i *int
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(*i)) // dereference of null pointer i
}
```

Why doesn't this code

```golang
unsafe.Sizeof(*i)
```

cause a runtime panic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Spec: Package unsafe:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Package_unsafe)

> Calls to `Alignof`, `Offsetof`, and `Sizeof` are **compile-time constant expressions** of type `uintptr`.

These functions are evaluated at compile time, no actual dereferencing happens at runtime.

This is possible because the pointed value is not needed, only information about its type is needed, which does not need dereferencing.

It's also documented at [`unsafe.Sizeof()`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Sizeof):

> The return value of Sizeof is a Go constant.

Constants in Go are compile-time constants.

Also see [Spec: Constants:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants)

> A constant value is represented by a [rune](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Rune_literals), [integer](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Integer_literals), [floating-point](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals), [imaginary](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Imaginary_literals), or [string](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals) literal, an identifier denoting a constant, a [constant expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions), a [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) with a result that is a constant, **or the result value of some built-in functions such as `unsafe.Sizeof` applied to any value**, `cap` or `len` applied to [some expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity), `real` and `imag` applied to a complex constant and complex applied to numeric constants.

See similar examples (which without passing them to `unsafe.Sizeof()` would panic at runtime or block indefinitely, but they work just fine):

```
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(*(*int8)(nil))) // 1, no dereferencing
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof([]int16{}[10])) // 2, no indexing
x := "hi"
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(x[10]))                          // 1, no indexing
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(map[interface{}]int{}[[]int{}])) // 8, no indexing
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof((interface{})(nil).(int16)))     // 2, no type assertion
i := 0
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(i / i)) // 8, no division by 0
i = -1
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(1 << i))                // 8, no negative shift count
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(make([]int, i)))        // 24, no negative length
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof((*[1]int)([]int{})))    // 8, no converting to bigger array
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof((func() int32)(nil)())) // 4, no function call
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(<-(chan int64)(nil)))   // 8, no receiving
var a, b interface{} = []int{}, []int{}
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(a == b)) // 1, no comparison
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0Jkg5HTyarJ).

Comment: thank you! We find more samples to show definition of `compile-time constant expressions` clearly: `const i = unsafe.Sizeof(*i)` assign from Sizeof to const value is valid.